# Does rooting require a custom ROM?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms

I've noticed that some apps say they require a rooted phone. Is it necessary to install a custom ROM in order to root a phone?

Edit: I should mention that I've seen [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone/1185#1185), but my phone isn't listed.

Comment: Apparently you can root the Flipside using z4root (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=835627), if you do so feel free to add the Flipside to that answer!

Comment: Cool I think it worked, I've updated that answer.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around, you need rooting to load custom ROM! Happy to see you managed :-) There's an app to check if you're really rooted: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck. Once you are permanently rooted you should see a "Superuser" icon among your apps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  For the most part, custom ROMs are just cosmetic changes to official ROMs and may come pre-rooted, but nothing about rooting requires a custom ROM.