# What do "root," "flash," and "ROM" mean?

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “flashing a custom ROM”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/what-is-the-meaning-of-flashing-a-custom-rom)

I have been looking for some good explanations of some words that have been frequently used the android developer communities like the XDA forums.

Some words I've seen but do not understand are:

root - (as far as I know it's the way of getting the super user access)

flash - don't know what this is

ROM - don't know either

I need a more descriptive explanation about these words and the related tools, mechanisms, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around the site will give you lots of answers.

Rooting:

- [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)
- [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

ROMs and Flashing:

- [What is the meaning of "flashing a custom ROM"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/what-is-the-meaning-of-flashing-a-custom-rom)
- [Does flashing a custom ROM require root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/does-flashing-a-custom-rom-require-root-access)
- [Does rooting require a custom ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/does-rooting-require-a-custom-rom)

Answer (score 1):

root - you are correct

flash - is to replace the OS that is installed on your phone with a custom ROM.

ROM - is a 3rd party created custom version of the Android OS.