# How to explain rooting, recovery and custom ROMs to a beginner?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc)
>   [What is the meaning of “flashing a custom ROM”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/what-is-the-meaning-of-flashing-a-custom-rom)
>   [What do “root,” “flash,” and “ROM” mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/what-do-root-flash-and-rom-mean)

I've got Dad a Galaxy Nexus as Christmas present. Being the obsessive tinkerer that I am, I already loaded CM10.1 nightlies on it. But I don't want to take care of the phone for ever.

He's a normal computer user, not exactly a noob in gadgets, so how do I explain rooting, custom recvory and ROMs in clear, non-jargon language? Last time I tried to explain, he stopped me at custom recovery and said he's better off using what I loaded on his Galaxy Ace.

The problem with that approach is that it leaves him incapable of solving all the minor niggles that come with custom ROMs. Also, I live on campus (college) and troubleshooting online would be so much easier if he knows the basics.

Comment: Both of the above eventually point to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc

Comment: @Peanut I was working my way through the duplicate tree, but my phone went mad and pressed enter on that one before I could go further.

Comment: Cyanogenmod only adds features for tinkerers in case of Nexus hardware. Leave it on Google's original firmware, it's also safer. I bet your dad will not miss root, openvpn, overclocking and all the rest hat CM adds. It's a different story for phones like the Galaxy Ace, though, when it adds new features like Voip, voice chat in Gtalk, etc.