# Why is root access required for a custom ROM?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, root-access

I'd like to be clear, and as my question indicates, I'm very ignorant of mobile devices in general so my apologies if this is common knowledge.

Say I want to install a custom ROM onto a device, then it would appear I need root access. I'm able to find out from every web page on *how* I can root a device, but I'm unable to find how *why* I need to root a device. I understand that rooting a device simply gives me root access on the device, but why is this needed? If I connect the phone to a PC then doesn't that give me access to the entire file system of the device? If so, then why can't I just overwrite the relevant parts of the FS with whatever ROM I want?

Also, why would rooting and using a custom ROM cause a device to be bricked? Couldn't I just overwrite the ROM that was causing the issue with the original one (that I'd thought on to back up! ;)).

Comment: `If I connect the phone to a PC then doesn't that give me access to the entire file system of the device?` - By default, no, it doesn't. It gives you access to a very specific portion of the filesystem (the "external" storage).

Comment: [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/does-rooting-require-a-custom-rom?rq=1) and [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/does-flashing-a-custom-rom-require-root-access?rq=1)

Comment: @t0mm13b None of those questions answer the *WHY* part. Guess I'll go ahead and put something here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Short answer:

For security and warranty reasons.

### Detailed answer:

This is mostly a precaution taken by most (not all!) device manufacturers to save them from too many service requests from "playing kiddies" (and the sort of people who want to try everything, even if they are not understanding anything). So those manufacturers took special actions to avoid "custom ROMs" (or, more precisely, any ROMs *not* provided by themselves) to be flashed.

As t0mm13b already pointed out in his comments above, by default you do *not* get physical access to your devices file system simply by connecting it via USB. Depending on device, Android version, and some more criteria, you get only to see parts. This might be the entire SD card (physical, in [UMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) mode), or even only "logical" access to parts of it via [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol). Some more privileged access can be gained via [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) when enabling *USB Debug* -- but with a stock ROM, in none of these cases you gain *full access*.

Now how are updates accomplished then? One very common practice is the use of a special ZIP file (`update.zip`). This is placed on the SD card, which is inserted into the device, and the device is booted into a special mode (recovery), where the `update.zip` can be applied from. **BUT:** the device checks the integrity of that `update.zip` -- it must be signed with the manufacturers key. For obvious reasons, that key is not freely available -- so no custom ROM can be installed this way on such a stock system.

All these things can be circumvented only with super-user access to the device -- which means: you must root it.

So that's for the **WHY** part -- while not handling the **HOW** part of rooting. Exactly as you asked for :)

---

### Update for even more details

As Liam pointed out in his comment that using `fastboot` would be a method to flash Custom ROMs without the pre-condition of having the device rooted, I did a little more research to find out about this. I will continue looking into this, but still already wanted to add my first results here.

Up to a certain point, Liam is right with this: It seems not only valid to Samsung devices (as I assumed first), but some other devices (not all) also support this method, without root being involved (aside from the fact that most Custom ROMs will ship rooted, of course -- so you will have root available *after* installing them). However, there are devices which seem to require root even for `fastboot flash` (see e.g. [TheUnlockr concerning the Iconia A100](http://theunlockr.com/2012/09/20/how-to-install-clockworkmod-recovery-on-the-acer-iconia-a100/), quote: *You must have rooted your device before doing this procedure.* -- and yes, they use `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` afterwards).

However, even if `fastboot` works for your unrooted device, there is one crucial point to consider:

> To Flash a ROM for your Android device with fastboot you must have an unlocked bootloader or an engineering bootloader

<sup>([Flashing Guide - Android - XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Flashing_Guide_-_Android))</sup>

Which means: If your bootloader is locked, you need to unlock it first, which will wipe (factory-reset) your device. So all data will be gone for good this way -- while with root you could have done a complete backup (Nandroid, Titanium Backup) before this step. However, starting with Android 4.0, this is no longer a real problem -- as you can do a full backup via ADB (see: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/16575/))

---

### Summary:

There are devices requiring to be rooted before you can flash a Custom ROM. If your device falls into this category, the reasons for *Why is root access required to flash a Custom ROM* are those mentioned above.

However: There are also devices which can be flashed using `fastboot` *without* being rooted before. If your device falls into that category, the question *Why is root access required to flash a Custom ROM* becomes invalid (the answer not, as *ex falso quodlibet sequitur* ("from false can follow anything") you can draw any conclusion from a wrong premise :)

That is: ***IF*** rooting is required, the above is ***WHY***.

Comment: You don't actually *need* root to install a custom ROM on most devices ;)

Comment: @LiamW As my question states - I'm very ignorant with mobile OSes, and Izzy has 13.3k reputation which indicates he knows a thing of two more about this than myself; as such, I assume his answer is fully correct as I don't know anything to the contrary; also his answer was also the highest voted (again indicating it's technically correct). Nevertheless if you believe his answer to be incorrect, feel free to update your answer and if the votes swing I'll change the accepted answer.

Comment: @LiamW You mean "on most *Samsung* devices". I never saw a device you could flash a custom ROM without rooting, sorry, and I saw some devices. Well, I kept away from plastic bombers... XD So technically, your last comment is incorrect :D

Comment: Its a chicken and egg... you need root to be able to flash a custom ROM and in order to flash a custom ROM, you *generally* need an unlocked boot-loader with a rooted recovery environment... and a rooted recovery environment such as CWM/TWRP....catch-22!

Comment: @t0mm13b just mentioned the "custom recovery". This is what works around the "signature" problem -- so one can flas an `update.zip` even when it's not signed with the manufacturers key -- so this is one more detail in the queue. I just don't see the "chicken-and-egg": root -> unlock -> CWM -> Custom ROM. No loop detected.

Comment: @LiamW It's hardly prejudice and you're quite right - high reputation doesn't always mean a valid answer, however considering I asked a question which I had no way of testing the answer I also rely on the community and their votes to find an acceptable answer. As I said, feel free to expand your answer which disproves the answer provided by Izzy and assuming the community agree, I'll happily make yours the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @R4D4 An accepted answer should be the one that helps you the most.  If you're not in a position to fully evaluate the answer then it's perfectly OK to not accept one.  Accepting the highest answer just because it's the highest, or the one from someone with high rep, is definitely frowned upon.  At the end of the day though it is your decision, no one should tell you differently.

Comment: Exactly -- peace again :) We decided, until proven otherwise, we both are correct -- depending on the circumstances (such as the hardware/manufacturer in question). I will dig into the `fastboot` topic again, and update my question later. May take a couple of days, as I'm quite busy at the moment (see chat for reasons ;)

Comment: @MatthewRead Can't agree more with your statement, however measuring "help" is difficult when I'm asking for an explanation. I don't generally accept answers based on rep or number of votes, but in this case I would. I have nothing to test the answers are correct, nor will I be in a position to fully understand the answers for quite a long time. Saying that, when the time comes when I can appreciate both answers, then I'd happily revise the accepted answer.

Comment: @Izzy Just to be clear, when you say I may be given access to the entire SD card through UMS mode, I'm assuming you mean the external SD card that may or may not be present rather than the internal memory holding the file system?

Comment: Correct -- I was just referring to the *real* card (which can be physically removed), not the internal one. And of course that's only true if the device supports UMS (which was usually the case before Android 4.0 if the device supported such a card).

Answer (score 7):

You generally don't need to root the phone to install the custom ROM, you have to root the phone to install a mechanism to install the custom ROM (such as a custom recovery image).

Some phones have unlockable bootloaders - you can flash boot and system.img files via the bootloader without the need to root.

You can also flash a custom recovery image using fastboot *without being rooted*.

You would need to install a custom recovery as the stock recovery checks that the update zip is signed - and most custom ROM zips *are not* signed.

You might need to root to install a custom recovery image if your device doesn't support fastboot, but generally you don't need to - it just comes with the image you install.

Samsung devices have download mode - no need to be rooted to use that, you just need ODIN.

> If I connect the phone to a PC then doesn't that give me access to the
>   entire file system of the device? If so, then why can't I just
>   overwrite the relevant parts of the FS with whatever ROM I want?

No, it doesn't. It gives you read only access, so you can't overwrite files in the `/system` directory. Root can be used to make `/system` read-writeable.

Comment: _"You generally don't need to root the phone to install the custom ROM, you have to root the phone to install a mechanism to install the custom ROM (such as a custom recovery image)."_ surely boils down to you do need root to go from having stock off-the-shelf OS to a custom ROM?

Comment: @GAThrawn Nope. You can flash a custom recovery using fastboot. You don't need to root to access fastboot (and sometimes you need to use fastboot to access root)

Comment: Many non-Samsung devices do not have unlockable bootloaders (especially older ones), though, so you can't flash a custom recovery without first exploiting the bootloader somehow or installing the recovery some other way (ROM Manager/Goo Manager). Often this does involve rooting, although that might not *always* be the case. I think that's what @GAThrawn and others are trying to get at. More manufacturers have started to move to offering a bootloader unlocking tool, but many still have not. Motorola devices, for example, are notoriously hard to get custom ROMs on compared to others.